# Is it possible to send information from the iPhone to the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I made some researches and I found that it was possible to call the iPhone from the Apple Watch Extension (with the method openParentApplication) but I didn't find anything talking about calling the Apple Watch from the iPhone app (like openChildApplication).

Is it possible ? If it is, can you please tell me how ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with [CFNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/index.html) and [Darwin notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html). You need to look at [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole).